# Concurrent Threads Reading a Socket

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have a simple Server-Client socket connection. I encapsulate all my data in objects which are sent backward and forward between the sockets, sent through ObjectStreams.

I have created a "HeartBeat" monitor, which runs in a separate thread, where both the server and the client, every 500ms, send a HeartBeat (empty object) backward and forward to check for connectivity, which works great. However, because of this, when I want to send other data between the server and client, it is mixed up with these HeartBeat objects.

For example my Server is expecting a Login object, but instead gets an object of instance HeartBeat.

My code is a simple client/server setup, so I don't think it'd be necessary to post their code, however, the HeartBeat code is as follows:

```
private static final int HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL = 500;

private void addHeartBeatMonitor(final Socket socket) {
    this.heartBeatTimer = new Timer();
    this.heartBeatTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                os.writeObject(new HeartBeat());
                ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                if (!(is.readObject() instanceof HeartBeat)) { throw new IOException(); }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOG.info("Received disconnect from " + getClientSocket().getInetAddress());
                heartBeatTimer.cancel();
                if (clientSocket != null) {
                    try {
                        clientSocket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {}
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {}
        }
    }, 0, HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL);
}
```

My options seem to be to as follows:

1. Ditch the HeartBeat functionality, although there seems to be no other reliable way to check the connection status.
2. Find some other kind of Socket implementation which will magically fix all of this for me.
3. Have a synchronized method which oversees all reads and writes to the socket, which discards HeartBeats and sends other objects where they're meant to be.
4. Some kind of synchronization magic.

Thanks in advance for any help!

**EDIT:**
Code which reads the Login object (server side):

```
User result = null;
try {
    ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(this.getInputStream());
    Login request = (Login) is.readObject(); ### ERROR ###
    result = this.mongoService.login(request);
    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(this.getOutputStream());
    os.writeObject(result);
} catch (IOException e) {
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {}
return result;
```

Exception as follows:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: model.HeartBeat cannot be cast to model.Login
    at socket.SocketServerWorker.login(SocketServerWorker.java:78)
    at socket.SocketServerWorker.<init>(SocketServerWorker.java:47)
    at socket.SocketServer$2.run(SocketServer.java:50)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: post the code where you get the object for your login etc in the client side

Comment: you can either use 2 separate sockets or main loop (where you process other messages) should take care of hearbeats too

Comment: The problem is your protocol seems to be completely time/order based. Consider a protocol where each object has a tag indicating what kind of message it is. That way the server can inspect it, and then decide what to do.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Added code as requested.

Comment: @dlev Would using different objects classify as an indication of what kind of message it is? Would there need to be a controller which oversees reads/writes from the socket? Also, if you could provide some code, or a link, I'd greatly appreciate it, can't seem to find much info on this.

Comment: @Cristian then instead of using the tcp socket for heartbeat.. use the udp socket for listening for the heartbeat and tcp for the object

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Thanks for the info. I'm going to look up how to use UDP, though it seems like I'm working around the problem instead of fixing it.

Comment: @Cristian Your current problem is a manifestation of a much more general one: how can your server differentiate between requests of different types? One common way is for each request to label itself, so that the server can decide prior to casting the object it just read. One way to do that would be to have each request derive from a base class which provides the identifier, and then for the server to operate based on that. Another option is to not be sending classes at all, and instead use a simple text/json/xml-based protocol, again with a "request type" field.

Comment: Consider having just one thread read all data from the socket constantly, and dispatch responses accordingly. If a heartbeat is received, process it. If a login response is received, call some event callback. In your login code on another thread, register the event handler, send your request, and wait for the response event to get triggered. Let the single reading thread take care of everything and pass responses back to whatever is interested in them. This way, request threads are independently waiting for the response thread to see the response they are interested in.

Comment: Another option is to have the heartbeat on a separate port and establish a separate socket for it. Not as flexible but easier to implement given the current state of your code.

Comment: This code isn't going to work anyway, as you have multiple object streams on the socket. I would just *send* the heartbeat request on the second thread, on the same object output stream the main thread is using, via suitable synchronization, and have the main thread deal with all the replies including the heartbeat response. It can use a read timeout to detect absence of a heartbeat response.

Comment: @JasonC That sounds perfect, though I'm not familiar with registering callbacks and handlers in Java. What is this technique called so I can learn it? Thanks again for your response.

Comment: @Jason Heartbeat on a second socket defeats the entire object. That socket is healthy: so what? It's the other socket he's concerned about.

Comment: @EJP The goal of the heartbeat is to check general connectivity to the server, not that specific socket. If he wants that specific socket he can just use setKeepAlive.

Comment: @JasonC And wait two hours. The existence of the socket and the absence of read timeouts and connection resets on it is sufficient. I would probably get rid of the heartbeat altogether.

Comment: @EJP I completely agree that read timeouts and connection resets are more than enough here, and that the heartbeat is redundant (unless of course you want to be notified immediately if the server goes down for monitoring purposes, even if your connection is idle - but that's probably not really necessary for a non-administrative client application).

Answer (score 0):

Consider doing something like this. I just threw this together, so it's obviously untested, but I'm sure you'll get the idea:

```
public class HeartBeatMonitor
{
    final Map<Class,Consumer> handlers = new HashMap<> ();
    final Socket sock;
    final ObjectInputStream is;
    final ObjectOutputStream os;

    public HeartBeatMonitor (final Socket sock)
    {
        try
        {
            this.sock = sock;
            this.is = new ObjectInputStream (sock.getInputStream ());
            this.os = new ObjectOutputStream (sock.getOutputStream ());
        }
        catch (final IOException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException (e);
        }
    }

    public <T> void setHandler (final Class<T> type, final Consumer<? super T> handler)
    {
        this.handlers.put (type, handler);
    }

    // This would be called in a loop
    void accept () throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        final Object o = this.is.readObject ();
        final Consumer handler = this.handlers.get (o.getClass ());
        if (handler != null)
            handler.accept (o);
        // Else default handler?
    }
}
```